# How do you unlock the C-Sides?

Tags: celeste

Every chapter in Celeste has an alternate B-Side version that’s unlocked by finding a hidden tape. However, I learned that it’s possible to unlock even more difficult C-Side versions.

How do you unlock the C-Side version of a chapter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to beat all B-Sides to unlock the C-Sides.

To get the B-Side version of the Core, you will need to collect all 8 crystal hearts from the normal versions and the 7 red crystal hearts from the first 7 B-Sides. Once you finished the final B-Side level, C-Sides will unlock. To play the Core C-Side, you also need to beat the other 7 C-Sides first.

Comment: Does anyone know why the developers decided to gate the content in this way? I would love to be able to play the more challenging stages without having to totally complete everything before them, it's a little frustrating.

Comment: I think the reason is one of "creeping difficulty" B-side is basically hard mode and C-side is basically Very Hard or Xtreme. Ideally if your here just for the story and not trying to explore every nook & cranny the optional difficulties aren't blatently there saying "You missed stuff go back". It's only there for the people who love the game and want more content to find. It's kind of genius when you think about it

Comment: @Callat totally makes sense; I'd love to try the C-sides but the necessary competency eludes me. I guess it's "git gud" for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In each chapter there is a Crystal Heart and a B-side. If you collect at least 4 Crystal Hearts, you can play the Chapter Core(If you already completed the other chapters). At the end of the Core you recieve a B-side and Crystal Heart. You recieve a Red Crystal Heart at the end of each B-side. After you collect/complete all the Crystal Hearts and Red Crystal Hearts, you can unlock the B-side of Chapter Core.

Finishing all the B-sides will unlock the C-sides. You recieve a Golden Crystal Heart at the end of each C-side.

Comment: How does this differ from [TestingTest's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/326836/181240)?